# C preprocessor: Change characters in __FILE__

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

The preprocessor fills the `__FILE__` define with the path to the source file, i.e. `module/src/sourcefile.c`

Is it possible to change this string during compile-time into `module_src_sourcefile_c`?

Comment: It's `"module/src/sourcefile.c"`, a string.

Comment: On Unix, the simplest technique would be to create a symlink (`ln -s module/src/sourcefile.c module_src_sourcefile.c`) and then compile `module_src_sourcefile.c`.  That doesn't put an underscore at the end (it ends `.c` instead of `_c`), but there isn't an obvious reason why that would be a problem...but then there isn't an obvious why you'd want to do the mapping in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: [*"These macros take no arguments and cannot be redefined."*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)
... and to my futile attempts, no.

You can always make a `char *` variable yourself though, which follows the pattern you desire.

Answer (score 1):

There are alternatives to `__FILE__` but it depends on your compiler. For example gcc/clang has `__BASE_FILE__`.

Or if you manage your own makefile then you can define your own, e.g., `-D___MYOWNFILENAME__=...`